# How do you average time, I keep getting 00:00:00.

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel

I am trying to average time.  The time format in the cells are 0:00:00.  I have changed the number section at the top to time however I keep getting 00:00:00 as the answer.

Comment: What is your question about? Excel?

Comment: Which program are you using? Excel?

Comment: It's meaningless to talk about averaging time.  Do you mean taking the average of several time INTERVALS?

Comment: Do you have an example of that data that you are using?  I opened my Excel, put in about 8 rows with your format `0:00:00` and used the following formula:  `=AVERAGE(B3:B9)` where `B3:B9` was the range of column data to average.  And the result came back properly.  So if we could see what your data was, that would be great, and let us know if it's a conversion issue, or what ever else.

Comment: Without clarification this question is incomplete. We need to know details: your values, your "average" function, and what program (Excel, LibraOffice, so on).

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be doing some thing wrong.

Refer to the screenshot of my samples with the formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that Excel does not recognize your times as times. To test change the number format of your time entries to "Number". This should cause your time values to change to a decimal number. If they still appear to be time values, Excel likely understands them as text values.

Comment: That's possible, Pynner, but if none of the times were recognised as numbers then the result of a simple `AVERAGE` would be `#DIV/0` not zero.....unless the formula used is not a simple average

Comment: good call... I hadn't really thought of that